# Set Strict-Transport-Security header for API

Tags: api, http, http-headers

Does it make sense to set the `Strict-Transport-Security` header for API responses *(i.e. requests that don't maintain state)* and most likely don't originate from browsers.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this off stackoverflow?

Answer (score 7):

The HSTS RFC does not mention APIs unfortunately.

Under 2.1 Use Cases it states:

```
o  Web browser user wishes to interact with various web sites (some
  arbitrary, some known) in a secure fashion.

o  Web site deployer wishes to offer their site in an explicitly
  secure fashion for their own, as well as their users', benefit.
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-2.1

As it explicitly states "web browser" I think it is safe to assume that HSTS was designed for resources accessed via a web browser.

If you think your API may be used by web browsers in the future then I'd recommend adding the HSTS header. If your API will never be accessed via a web browser then you don't need the HSTS header, however, it may be worth adding it to 'future proof' your API incase you decide it should be accessed via a web browser in the future (and/or you allow HTTP connections in the future).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but The HSTS header is a browser instruction and the browser has to be the client party handling the response. For data requests (AJAX, XHR, Fetch api) the inclusion of this header does not mean anything as the browser is not handling the response; The frontend code that is part of the site is. Is my thinking on this accurate ?

Comment: @MattM you can inspect and read the body of the response, but it's browser's responsibility to deliver it securely. In fact you can see it being one of the steps of the `fetch` flow: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch

Comment: Right the browser is responsible for handle the TLS / HTTPS request and response, but the browser during the `fetch` command is not responsible for and does not do anything with the HSTS header. So if fetch is called with http the browser is not going to force the request to be https. Right ?

Comment: @MattM I think point `10` in the link above states exactly that. Upgrade the scheme to `https` if target domain is a known HSTS host to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

HSTS is generally a browser only instruction. Other callers, such as phone or desktop apps, do not obey the instruction. Even within browsers, a single authenticated call to an API over HTTP has risks on insecure networks. The secure approach is to configure API projects to only listen to and respond over HTTPS.

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio